# angular 4 print array with json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, templates

I have this array from my .ts file that have to print in my .html :

```js
myArray: ["03/05/2018", "2:54", "xoxo", "briefing", "your", [{
    "Id": "1",
    "Time": "20:54",
    "Topic": "mmmmm",
    "GUEST1": {
      "Role": "HS",
      "Infos": "Alaska"
    },
    "GUEST2": {
      "Role": "GS",
      "Infos": "Arizona,"
    }
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "Time": "21:55",
    "Topic": "vvvvv",
    "GUEST1": {
      "Role": "CS",
      "Infos": "Georgia"
    },
    "GUEST2": {
      "Role": "GS",
      "Infos": "Florida"
    },
    "GUEST3": {
      "Role": "HS",
      "Infos": "Delaware,"
    }
  },
  {
    "Id": "3",
    "Time": "1:56",
    "Topic": "fffff",
    "GUEST1": {
      "Role": "GS",
      "Infos": "Colorado"
    }
  }
]]
```

how can I do it?
 I can print the first 5 items with *ngFor but have problem when it comes to the JSON items. is it possible to do substring comparison on GUEST to print the differents values of keys?
Something like :

Date : 03/05/2018
Time : 2:54
Name : xoxo
Subject : briefing
other : your
Block Id : 1
Time :20:54
Topic: mmmmmm
Guest 1 role : HS
Guest 1 Infos : Alaska
Guest 2 role : GS
Guest 2 Infos : Arizona

Comment: What exactly you want to print

Comment: what you want to show in the html?

Comment: Just use `json` pipe in template.

Comment: want to print each item array in a new line.  I can print the first 5 items with *ngFor but have problem when it comes to the JSON items. is it possible to do substring comparison on `GUEST`  to print the differents values of keys?

Answer (score 1):

Use `pre` tag to show any formatted string values. If you need your data to be shown as formatted, use `JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2)` or angular's build-in `json` pipe.

```
<pre [innerHTML]="formattedResult | json"></pre>

// alternate way
<pre [innerHTML]="formattedResult"></pre>

arr = [...];   // your arr data;
formattedResult = JSON.stringify(this.arr, null, 2);   // format
```

See **[demo with pre](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aqtuz9?file=src/app/app.component.html)** and **[demo(key-value) with ngFor](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uwzkyv?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: is there a way to to go through the array an have each item in a row of a table or on a new line? I've updated my question with the formatting of the array

Comment: @mamesaye so you want a two columns key-value table?

Comment: @mamesaye for that, consider using **Object.keys** along with *ngFor

Comment: how do you loop to get all the JSON object since GUESTX are not in an array?

Comment: @mamesaye I have added a complex working demo, see whether it helps. Since your data is a little complex, I just give a first layer implementation as an example.

Comment: ok, but how will you use the newly created index to access the values?

Comment: I see a number in front of each JSON object : 0, 1, 2 and 3

Comment: @mamesaye basically array can also be considered as **object** like {0: item1, 1: item2, 2: item3}. `0, 1, 2 and 3 ` is the object's keys, following column iscorresponding value to each of them.

Comment: ok, so <pre [innerHTML]="stringify(item[key].Topic, null, 2)"></pre> gives me the value of topic. Thanks but how do you loop the guest to get the values?

Comment: @mamesaye For **ArrayLikeObject**, it's ok to go. But for normal array, use `myArray[0].Topic` instead.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to iterate over array use `*ngFor`.

Else simply use `json` pipe like this

```
{{myArray | json}}
```

> PS: You are defining array wrongly here like `myArray:` , `:` is used to declare type of array whereas you are assigning values to array so you should use `myArray =`

## [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oyforg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)